# Git pull from a repo and push to another

Tags: git, github, push, pull

I have a repo_1 on github with two branches: `master` and `gh-pages`.
Then I have a repo_2 with a single branch: `master`.

It is possible to pull from the `gh-pages` branch on repo_1 last updates and push them on `master` branch on repo_2?

#### Update:

After trying this

```
git pull repo_1 gh-pages
git push repo_2 gh-pages:master
```

When I push to second repo I have this error:

```
! [rejected] gh-pages -> master (fetch first) error: 
   failed to push some refs to 'github.com/gnardel/gnardell.github.io.git';
   hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

Comment: `git pull repo_1 gh-pages; git push repo_2  gh-pages:master`

Comment: When I push to second repo I have this error:   ! [rejected]        gh-pages -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/gnardell/gnardell.github.io.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.

Answer (score 0):

For the error

> failed to push some refs to 'github.com/gnardel/gnardell.github.io.git';
>   hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do

This happens if you initialized a new github repo with README and/or LICENSE file, which is a new commit that you don't have locally. You need to pull and merge it first:

```bash
git checkout gh-pages
git pull repo_2  master:gh-pages
# you may need to fix some merge conflicts
git push repo_2  gh-pages:master
```

Now you will be able to push your repository to github. Basically, you have to merge any new commits on github before you can push.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. When I try to pull from repo_2 I have this error:  
 `! [rejected]        master     -> gh-pages  (non-fast-forward)`

Comment: You can seperate the `pull` operation into [fetch and merge](https://help.github.com/articles/fetching-a-remote/). If you don't know this already, it's better to go throgh Git 101 first before you continue.